# Problem with solving integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

> I wanna calculate the following integral:
>   $$\int_{0}^{1} 1 + \sin^2 \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) + \frac{1}{x^2} \cos^2 \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) - \frac{1}{x} \sin \left( \frac{2}{x} \right) dx$$

I substituted $x=1/u$ to get 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{1} \left[ 1 + \sin^2(u) + u^2 \cos^2(u) - u \sin(2u) \right] \left( \frac{-1}{u^2} \right) du$$

Is there an easier way , which I don't see or is it really so long ?

Thank you !

Comment: it looks like $ ( cos(1/x) /x-sin(1/x))^2$ .....with $sin(2/x)=2cos(1x)sin(1/x) $...not sure it will be more simple

Comment: @Isham:$(sin(1/x)-cos(1/x)/x)^2$ yes

Comment: For the 1 you can get it out of the integrand since it has value 1  $\int_0^11dx =1$

Comment: @Isham: thanks, already thought of this, but this integral seems to be ugly though

Comment: @Isham: Thank you , I'm gonna calculate around :)

Comment: The antiderivative can be computed but there is a serious problem when $x\to 0^+$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:
$$sin^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 } } cos^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) -\frac { sin\left( \frac { 2 }{ x }  \right)  }{ x } dx=sin^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) +\frac { 1 }{ x^{ 2 } } cos^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) -\frac { 2sin\left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) \cos { \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }  }{ x } =\\ ={ \left( \sin { \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) -\frac { 1 }{ x } \cos { \left( \frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 }$$